# How To Retrieve a Secret From Azure Key Vault Node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm looking for a code sample which demonstrates how to connect to an azure key vault and grab a secret from the vault without having to store creds in plain text but instead using certificates and an SPN for authentication to the vault. Has anyone done anything like this before who is willing to shed some light on this?

I'm trying to securely retrieve credentials from azure without ever having to save creds locally, and this has proven to be harder than I originally thought.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use certificate based authentication while accessing Azure key vault.

Here is a very good article on the same using dot net.

[Certificate base authentication](https://azurecto.com/azure-keyvault-authenticating-with-certificates-and-reading-secrets/)

Alternatively Azure Key Vault provides a way to securely store credentials and other keys and secrets, but your code needs to authenticate to Key Vault to retrieve them. Managed Service Identity (MSI) makes solving this problem simpler by giving Azure services an automatically managed identity in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). You can use this identity to authenticate to any service that supports Azure AD authentication, including Key Vault, without having any credentials in your code.

Run the assign-identity command to create the identity for this application:

```
az webapp identity assign --name <app_name> --resource-group "<YourResourceGroupName>"
```

This command is the equivalent of going to the portal and switching Managed service identity to On in the web application properties.

**Assign permissions to your application to read secrets from Key Vault**

```
 {
      "principalId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "tenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "type": "SystemAssigned"
    }
```

Then, run this command using the name of your Key Vault and the value of PrincipalId copied from above:

```
az keyvault set-policy --name '<YourKeyVaultName>' --object-id <PrincipalId> --secret-permissions get

Deploy the Node App to Azure and retrieve the secret value
```

Deploy your node js app ,After this when you browse https://.azurewebsites.net you can see the secret value. Make sure that you replaced the name with your vault name